# unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb0cd214f40'

Tags: ios, swift

I have a xib file like under and I want a method that when click the left-arrow it turns back to front view.

**ViewController**

```
@IBOutlet weak var navigationImage: NavigationImage!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    customizeNavigation(
}

private func customizeNavigation(){
    navigationImage.tapLeftImage(viewController: self)
}
```

**navigationImage**

```
func tapLeftImage(viewController: UIViewController){
let leftIconTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: viewController, action: #selector(backToTop))
      leftImage.addGestureRecognizer(leftIconTap)
      leftImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}

@objc func backToTop() {
}
```

when I click the leftImage,it comes out the error.Where I get wrong?Thank you for your help.

Comment: Show the entire error message, please.

Comment: @matt ilistening_chounouryoku_check[66619:4800187] [Storyboard] Unknown class view in Interface Builder file. 2020-02-04 10:48:31.984863+0900 ilistening_chounouryoku_check[66619:4800187] -[ilistening_chounouryoku_check.CopyrightViewController backToTop]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb0cd214f40 2020-02-04 10:48:31.989723+0900 ilistening_chounouryoku_check[66619:4800187] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ilistening_chounouryoku_check.CopyrightViewController backToTop]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb0cd214f40'

Comment: Well, that's a lot of errors. But let's focus on one. You are setting up the tap gesture recognizer with target `viewController` and action `backToTop`. But the function `backToTop` is not _in_ the view controller. It is in the navigationImage.

Comment: @matt So what should I do? because I want to use the **backToTop** function in many ViewController, I hope it is in **navigationImage**

Comment: I don't know what you _want_ to do. You should do something that makes sense. Saying the view controller is the target if the view controller doesn't have the action method does not make sense — it causes a crash (as you have discovered). The target has to be someone who contains the action method. That is what a target _is_.

Comment: @matt sorry for my explanation.I wanna pass the **ViewController** to **backToTop** as parameter and call dismiss function to back to the front view.now I change the target parameter to self but don't know how to pass **ViewController** to **backToTop**.

Comment: @matt finally,I found the resolution ,thank you for your help!!!

Comment: That's great. You can answer your own question if you like.